# Cannot find save location of screen recording

Tags: 22.04, desktop-recording

I am trying to record my screen using the included screen recorder. As I understand, this is a new feature in Ubuntu 22. I press `Print screen` like I would to take a screenshot, select the record option, and start recording. It seems to work, and a timestamp and stop button show up in the top right of the screen. I can click the stop button to stop recording. Problem is, I cannot seem to find where the videos are being saved to, if they're even being saved at all. I would assume they're supposed to be saved in `~/Videos/`, but they are not there. How can I find/change where these videos are saved?
I am running Ubuntu Desktop 22.04.1.

Edit: Someone has mentioned that the default location is `~/Videos/Screencasts/`, however that directory does not exist for me. I tried creating it and making a recording, but it still does not appear to save.

Comment: Something is wrong, or you are looking in the wrong location, or you are not using the screenshot/recorder feature of Gnome Shell 42. Check your syslog and journal for clues. Double-check the facts presented in your Question. (For example, 'Ubuntu 22' != Ubuntu Desktop 22.04)

Comment: @user535733 I added clairification in my question where I could. I was going to add a screenshot of what it looks like, but as you could imagine, that wouldn't really work lol. You mentioned checking if I am using the screenshot/recorder feature of Gnome Shell 42. How would I verify this?

Comment: If the tool is provided via `snap` and your homedir is not under `/home` it can not access your homedir due to security restrictions.

Comment: @Marco I don't know whether or not it's provided by snap, but my home dir is under `/home`

Answer (score 1):

Single screenshots are saved in `~/Pictures/Screenshots/`

Desktop videos (screencasts) are saved in `~/Videos/Screencasts/`

There is currently no setting included with a stock install of Gnome Shell to change those locations. However several workarounds exist with Gnome Extensions.

Gnome Shell is Open Source. The Gnome developers welcome contributions to add features to Gnome Shell, and welcome volunteers to maintain and provide support for those contributions.

Comment: That directory did not exist for me, and when I created it, recordings were not saved there.